# Мессенджер на основе REST

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, rest

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как можно реализовать мессенджер на основе REST-сервиса. Задача отправка сообщений юзеру по его имени или id. Как подобное можно реализовать?

Comment: а в чём, собственно, сложность?

Comment: Больше деталей, пожалуста.

Comment: Ну есть возможность войти или зарегестрироваться пользователю. После входа он может общаться с другими пользователями, отправляя им сообщения по id пользователя. Будет список пользователей с их id.